# Not able to record audio on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I am not able record to any audio input neither from the inbuilt mic nor an external earphone on my Ubuntu running on Virtual Box.

I have tried:

- Ensuring earphone and inbuilt work properly on other platforms(earphone mic on mobile and inbuilt mic on windows).
- Raising the volume bar to max in alsamixer
- Removing the 'mm' under sections by pressing 'm'
- Typing the command `$pavucontrol` and setting the profile to analog stereo duplex under configurations tab

My alsamixer playback settings: [image]

My alsamixer capture settings: [image]

To record audio I am using the command

```
$arecord --format=S16_LE --duration=5 --rate=16000 --file-type=raw out.raw
```

To hear the recorded audio back, i am using the command:

```
$ aplay --format=S16_LE --rate=16000 out.raw
```

(I hear nothing back. No sound not even noise)

Details about card and alsa:

```
Alsamixerversion -> Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k4.15.0-36-generic.

Card -> I82801AAICH  : ICH - Intel 82801AA-ICH 
                       Intel 82801AA-ICH with AD1980 at irq 21
```

Please help.